# Catalyst Control Center

Tags: drivers, graphics, catalyst

I have this installed, but then what? Is this an application that you can open up and modify or is it like a driver that you just download and not touch again?

Answer (score 0):

Both. You have the Control Center which manages the driver and the driver itself. I think AMD delivers both in the same package. You can muck around in the Control Center app till you have settings you find satisfactory, at which point you probably won't have to touch it again.

Comment: Problem is, I cannot find the app for control center, theres only the instal app which I have already followed and finished

Comment: @Tator_Soldier does `locate amdcccle` show anything?